# Veins_inet: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5Veins17VeinsInetMobilityE' when building in OMNet 5.1.1

Tags: omnet++, veins

I imported veins_inet subproject into OMNet 5.1.1 on Windows-64 machine and tried to build. Everything went okay (building inet and veins) until receiving this error when it starts building veins_inet:

```
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:41:1: warning: 'Veins::VeinsInetMobility::VeinsInetMobility()' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
 VeinsInetMobility::VeinsInetMobility() :
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:54:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::preInitialize(std::__cxx11::string, const inet::Coord&, std::__cxx11::string, double, double)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 void VeinsInetMobility::preInitialize(std::string external_id, const inet::Coord& position, std::string road_id, double speed, double angle) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:61:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::nextPosition(const inet::Coord&, std::__cxx11::string, double, double)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 void VeinsInetMobility::nextPosition(const inet::Coord& position, std::string road_id, double speed, double angle) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:75:8: warning: 'virtual double Veins::VeinsInetMobility::getMaxSpeed() const' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 double VeinsInetMobility::getMaxSpeed() const {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:79:7: warning: 'virtual inet::Coord Veins::VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentPosition()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 Coord VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentPosition() {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:83:7: warning: 'virtual inet::Coord Veins::VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentSpeed()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 Coord VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentSpeed() {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:87:19: warning: 'virtual inet::EulerAngles Veins::VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentAngularPosition()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 inet::EulerAngles VeinsInetMobility::getCurrentAngularPosition() {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:96:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::initialize(int)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 void VeinsInetMobility::initialize(int stage) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:126:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::handleMessage(omnetpp::cMessage*)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 void VeinsInetMobility::handleMessage(cMessage *message) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:130:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::updateVisualRepresentation()' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
 void VeinsInetMobility::updateVisualRepresentation() {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:137:6: warning: 'virtual void Veins::VeinsInetMobility::emitMobilityStateChangedSignal()' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
 void VeinsInetMobility::emitMobilityStateChangedSignal() {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_inet.dll
../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.o: In function `Veins::VeinsInetMobility::VeinsInetMobility()':
C:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\veins_inet\src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:47: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5Veins17VeinsInetMobilityE'
C:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\veins_inet\src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc:47: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5Veins17VeinsInetMobilityE'
../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.o: In function `Veins::VeinsInetMobility::~VeinsInetMobility()':
C:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\veins_inet\src/./veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.h:37: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5Veins17VeinsInetMobilityE'
C:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\veins_inet\src/./veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.h:37: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5Veins17VeinsInetMobilityE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:89: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_inet.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/omnetpp-5.1.1/samples/veins_inet/src'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
```

I tried using gcc-release instead of gcc-debug but the problem stays. Any help please? Thanks.

Max,

Comment: Is this error specific to building on Windows or does it occur on Linux or Mac OS X as well?

Comment: I didn't try it on Linux or Mac. It looks like it's a Windows issue because I didn't find this issue anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it definitely looks like a Windows issue. Today i got exactly the same error, when building veins_inet under Windows for the first time. Last month I was forced to reinstall my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit) workstation several times and never had the same issue - it compiled flawlessly.

Comment: I tried to build veins_inet in OMNet 5.0 with veins 4.5 on the same Windows machine and it works perfectly. It could be an issue related to veins 4.6 on OMNet 5.1.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your VeinsInetMobility.h if there is class INET_API xx : public. The "without dllimport attribute" warning and "undefined reference" error may be caused by "INET_API" in some omnet windows edition. You can just remove "INET_API" to see if it is OK. Just for advice.